# Prove that $\operatorname{fib}(n)$ is the closest integer to $\frac{\phi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, computer-science, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

From [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.2):

> Exercise 1.13: Prove that $\operatorname{fib}(n)$ is the closest integer to
>   $$\frac{\phi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}, \text{ where } \phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2.$$ Hint: Let
>   $$\varphi=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2.$$ Use induction and the definition of the Fibonacci numbers (see 1.2.2) to prove that $$\operatorname{fib}(n)=\frac{\phi^{n}-\varphi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}.$$

My background:

- Some programming experience, including recursion
- Some algebra
- very basic recursive sequence (just explored)
- Very basics of induction (just explored)

I thought I'd take a stab at this exercise. I am aware I may not be able to do this because it might require some mathematical tools I am not yet able to use, but I just want to try it and see what happens.

Let $p1(n)$ be the proposition that $$\operatorname{fib}(n)=\frac{\phi^{n}-\varphi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Base case: $p_1(0)$ is true.
$$\operatorname{fib}(0)=\frac{\phi^{0}-\varphi^{0}}{\sqrt{5}}=0$$

Inductive hypothesis: assume $p_1(n)$ is true.
$$\operatorname{fib}(n)=\frac{\phi^{n}-\varphi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Inductive step: $p_1(n)$ is true $ \implies p_1(n+1)$ is true
$$\operatorname{fib}(n+1)=\frac{\phi^{n+1}-\varphi^{n+1}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Solution:
we can rewrite the left side as:
$$\operatorname{fib}(n)+\operatorname{fib}(n-1)=\frac{\phi^{(n+1)}-\varphi^{(n+1)}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Since I know that $$\operatorname{fib}(n)=\frac{\phi^{n}-\varphi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$ I can substitute.

$$\frac{(\phi^{n}-\varphi^{n})}{\sqrt{5}}+((\phi^{(n-1)}-\varphi^{(n-1)})/\sqrt{5})=(\phi^{(n+1)}-\varphi^{(n+1)})/\sqrt{5}$$

Now I have to combine the terms. I have to make sure of two things:
$$\phi^{n}+\phi^{(n-1)}=\phi^{(n+1)}$$ and
$$\varphi^{n}+\varphi^{(n-1)}=\varphi^{(n+1)}$$

It is stated in the book that:
$fi^2=fi+1$
When I used this equation, I got the following transformations.

- $$\phi^{1}=\phi$$
- $$\phi^{2}=(\phi+1)$$
- $$\phi^{3}=(2\phi+1)$$
- $$\phi^{4}=(3\phi+2)$$
- $$\phi^{5}=(5\phi+3)$$

Much like how the fibonacci numbers are iteratively generated. More generally, I would say that:
$$\phi^{n}=\operatorname{fib}(n)\phi+\operatorname{fib}(n-1)$$
This is just a guess, I will assume it for now. I will try to prove this at the end.

$\varphi$ is the same. For some reason the equation.
$\varphi^{2}=\varphi+1$
also appears to hold. I would assume $\varphi^{n}$ is the same as with $\phi^{n}$.

So, back to $p_1$

Using my transformations of $\phi^{n}$ above:
$$\phi^{(n+1)}=\operatorname{fib}(n+1)\phi+\operatorname{fib}(n)$$

I can finally confirm that:

$$\phi^{n}+\phi^{(n-1)}=(\operatorname{fib}(n)\phi+\operatorname{fib}(n-1))+(\operatorname{fib}(n-1)\phi+\operatorname{fib}(n-2))$$
using the definition of $\operatorname{fib}$:
$$\operatorname{fib}(n)\phi+\operatorname{fib}(n-1)\phi=\operatorname{fib}(n+1)\phi$$
$$\operatorname{fib}(n-1)+\operatorname{fib}(n-2)=\operatorname{fib}(n)$$
add all = $$\operatorname{fib}(n+1)\phi+\operatorname{fib}(n)=\phi^{(n+1)}$$

I believe since $\varphi$ and $\phi$ appear to have the same transformations, I think I already proved $$\varphi^{n}+\varphi^{(n-1)}=\varphi^{(n+1)}$$

So, I believe $p_1(n+1)$ is true and I believe I have proven $p_1$.

Now, on to the original exercise: $\operatorname{fib}(n)$ is the closest integer to $\phi^{n}/\sqrt{5}$$ because $$\operatorname{fib}(n)-\varphi^{n}/\sqrt{5}=\phi^{n}/\sqrt{5}$$. Is this correct?

Now, I would like to prove $\phi^{n}$ because I have just guessed it earlier.

Let $p_2(n)$ be the proposition that $$\phi^{n}=\operatorname{fib}(n)\phi+\operatorname{fib}(n-1)$$ for all positive integers $>0$

base case: $p_2(1)$ is true.
$$\phi^{1}=\phi+0=\phi$$

Inductive hypothesis: assume $$\phi^{n}=\operatorname{fib}(n)\phi+\operatorname{fib}(n-1)$$ for all positive integers $>0$

Inductive step: $p_2(n)$ implies $p_2(n+1)$ is true
$$\phi^{(n+1)}=\operatorname{fib}(n+1)\phi+\operatorname{fib}(n)$$ for all positive integers $> 0$

Solution:
$$\phi^{(n+1)}=\phi\cdot \phi^{n}$$
so:
$$\phi^{(n+1)}=(\operatorname{fib}(n)\phi+\operatorname{fib}(n-1))\phi$$
Since $\operatorname{fib}(n)$ is the closest integer to $\phi^{n}/\sqrt{5}$, we can substitute this:
$$\phi^{(n+1)}=((\phi^{n}/\sqrt{5})\phi+(\phi^{(n-1)}/\sqrt{5}))fi$$
$$((\phi^{n}/\sqrt{5})\phi)\phi=(\phi^{(n+1)}/\sqrt{5})\phi=\operatorname{fib}(n+1)\phi$$
$$(\phi^{(n-1)}/\sqrt{5})\phi=\phi^{(n)}/\sqrt{5}=\operatorname{fib}(n)$$
add all
$$\operatorname{fib}(n+1)\phi+\operatorname{fib}(n)$$
That I think is the solution.

Now, I don't really know if what I did is correct. I just assume some things (e.g. $\phi^{2}=\phi+1$) but I don't really know why that is true. One thing that bothers me so much is: In order to prove that $\operatorname{fib}(n)$ is the closest integer to $$\phi^{n}/\sqrt{5}$$, I first have to prove $p_1$. In order to make sure that $\phi^{n}$ generates like fibonacci numbers on $p_1$, I proved $p_2$. But $p_2$ also requires me to assume that $\operatorname{fib}(n)$ is the closest integer to $$\frac{\phi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}!$$ I feel like I am doing something very wrong here.

Did I do something right? Or I have no idea what I'm really doing?

Comment: This is somewhat hard to read.  [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) gives a good way to express Fibonacci numbers in terms of things like $\phi$.

Comment: For the inductive step, $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are the solutions to $x^2-x-1=0$. So $\phi^{n+1}-\phi^n-\phi^{n-1}=$ $\phi^{n-1}(\phi^2-\phi -1)=$ $\phi^{n-1}(0)=0.$ Similarly with $ \phi$ replaced by $\varphi.$....... We have $|\varphi|<1$ so  for $n\geq 0$ we have $ |fib(n)-\phi^n/\sqrt 5\;|=|\varphi^n/\sqrt 5\;|\leq$ $ 1\sqrt 5 <1/2. $ If $x\in \Bbb Z$ and $|x-y|<1/2$ then $x$ is the unique closest integer to $y.$